# query generator by dataset and id list

Tags: .net, sql, dataset

I search a way to create query by using a dataset as database simulator.
The dataset contain each table with primary key column. It also have foreign keys.
[simulate database vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186174/simulate-database-vb-net)

I search a way to create the "Where" part by giving a list of Key/Value.

The dataset will be empty, its only a way to create an exponential list of query.

Sample:
sample:

```
Table A
colA
```

And

```
Table B
colB
colD
```

linked by

```
Table C
colA
colB
```

and

```
Table D
colD
```

I give the list

```
[colA] 1
[colA] 2
[colA] 3
[colB] 5
[colB] 6
[colD] 8
```

I want a query of every item on Table A containing element specified in the list.

```
Select * 
from TableA
where colA in (1,2,3)
and colA in (
            select colA 
            from TableC
            where colB in (5,6)         
            and colB in (
                            select colB
                            from TableB
                            where colD in (8)
                        )
            )
```

So I'm searching an algo to create the query. like any query generator working.

---

I can want data from any of those tables.

this of a function

```
function GetSubQuery(table, list(of keyValue) as string
```

my sample ask for TableA. but I can want TableB or C or D. with the same id List.

---

Situation (simulation)

```
I want table A,B or D.

I can ask for table A, giving id from colD. 
I can ask for table A, giving id from colB.
I can ask for table A, giving id from colA.
I can ask for table A, giving id from colB and colD.
I can ask for table A, giving id from colB and colA.
I can ask for table A, giving id from colB and colD and colA.

I can ask for table B, giving id from colD.
...
```

we have here 18 possibilities.

But I dont want a query for the max possibilities and use it for every possibilites.
I mean the query for "table A, giving id from colB and colD and colA." should not be use if you only have id from colA.
Because it can have a lot of data in the other table and you will search inside without needed.

the algo need to know, if you dont need to go there, you dont.

Comment: Does your query do what you want?  It is unclear what the question is.

Comment: "So I'm searching an algo to create the query. like any query generator working.". Whatever I put on my list of column. the algo will create the query. I dont want to create each possible way. because the algo will be use with more than 4 tables.

Comment: I add a lot of thing in the question. But that made it probably difficult to understand. I will edit it for clarified my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataSets and DataTables do not support TSQL.
TSQL pretty just talks to a database engine.

You can define PK, PK FK relationships, and walk those relations.
[Navigating DataRelations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6s958d6.aspx)
You can cast to List and use LINQ to query.

[LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Or you can just iterate the rows and do equality comparison.

SQL CE is an embedded database that supports TSQL.

Another option is XML and use LINQ to query the the XML.

Personally I would do this with classes (not DataSets) and overrite gethashcode and equals. 
DataSets are heavy and slow and collection have come a long way in .NET.
Use HashSets (or Dictionary of KeyedCollection) for the collections.
Even have class TblATblD that represents the join and use HashSet.
If your ID can be Int16 then you can pack the two Int16 into Int32 on TblATblD.
I do this with Users Groups and then a UrsGrp.
User can see certain Fields.
Queries kind of like what you are talking about all in LINQ.

Comment: I'm not sure, but its like you think I want the result of my query. I do not, I need a way to create TSQL query because I got too many possibilities. Maybe I dont understand your answer.

Comment: when you said "No DataSets and DataTables do not support TSQL." I dont want use the dataset with tsql, I want to use it as simulation for linked table and knowing where are the column listed on my columnList

Comment: OK then you should remove the dataset as a database simulator are that is where I got TSQL.  Yes you can do this with LINQ.  I will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: dataRelation seems interesting. I'll look at it a little closer. tank you